# What are the limits of volume for JourneyBuilder with Marketing Cloud Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are using Journey Builder connected to our Sales Cloud instance.

In our journeys we use Salesforce Entry Data.

We mostly use “Sales Cloud Campaign” as entry mode for journey, but we have a few journeys that are using regular Salesforce data with “is updated/meets criteria” as entry aswell.

We are having some issue when inserting big volumes into campaign in Sales Cloud, not all come to Journey.

I have been told to check this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm and this: https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5

But I don’t see any volume limitations listed.

Can somebody please tell me what is the maximum number of subscriber that we can push to journey in one batch using:

- Salesforce Campaign as entry source for journey (adding new members to a Campaign in progress that is connected to journey)
- Salesforce data updates as entry source for journey (running journey with filter criteria and in sales cloud we do a mass upload of contacts that match this criteria and should be added to welcome journey)

Thank you your help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are obviously governor limits on the CRM flows used by Journey Builder. If you're looking at very large numbers of records being added to your campaigns in one go, you could possibly consider Synchronising your Campaign Member object to Marketing Cloud Data Extensions and use an Automation to inject into Journey Builder from the synchronised DE using a Query Activity or Filter Activity. This obviously doesn't cover off real-time injection of the Campaign Members into Journey Builder, but it'd scale quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a difference in Journey Builder's performance based on Entry Source whether you use SF DE and usual DE. However, there some [best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320344&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) that hints at processing volume, e.g.

> Typically Journey Builder has a processing rate of 500k/hr/Tenant. You can get up to 2M/hr/Tenant assuming all best practices in this document have been followed. Processing speed is for all running/finishing journeys in the same time frame.